# Является ли снег ненастьем

Tags: лексика

Можно ли снег назвать ненастьем? Или ненастье скорее связывается с дождем и его признаками (слякоть, лужи, серые тучи)? Или вернее было бы сказать о снеге: "непогода"?

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Так и говорят, если снег мешает чьим-то планам.

Из-за сильных снегопадов часто перекрывают въезд/выезд в города. Или снегом засыпало весь двор и нужно его разгребать. Из-за сильного снега, который ухудшает видимость, часто случаются автомобильные аварии.

Вывод: снег может быть намного опасней дождя.

Comment: Просто в словаре ненастье определяется как "дождливая, пасмурная погода".

Comment: Пасмурное небо с дождем, ситничком, с градом, крупой, снегом, метелью, бурей - в словаре Даля.

Comment: В народе это слово ещё используется в значении "неудача". Глупому счастье, умному ненастье.

Comment: А могут ли снег, метель, крупа называться  мокредью (мокретью), или мокреть сообщает уже исключительно о дожде и связанных с ним явлениях?

Comment: Мокредь - сырость, грязь, дождливая погода. В другом словаре - это "мокрый снег". Там же и много похожих слов. https://i.imgur.com/30v5OoG.png

Answer (score 1):

Сильный снегопад часто является ненастьем. Вот пример:

" Пошел мелкий снег — и вдруг повалил хлопьями. Ветер завыл; сделалась метель. В одно
мгновение темное небо смешалось со снежным морем. Все исчезло. «Ну, барин, — закричал ямщик, — беда: буран!»...

Я выглянул из кибитки: все было мрак и вихорь. Ветер выл с такой свирепой выразительностию, что казался одушевленным; снег засыпал меня и Савельича; лошади шли шагом — и скоро стали. «Что же ты не едешь?» — спросил я ямщика с нетерпением. «Да что ехать? — отвечал он, слезая с облучка, — невесть и так куда заехали: дороги нет, и мгла кругом». "

— А. С. Пушкин "Капитанская Дочка"

Comment: А где здесь слово "ненастье"?

Comment: @Владимир  Этого слова здесь нет. Но описано здесь именно ненастье. (Неужели это надо объяснять?)